# Hard time understanding what the significance of the tail of a sequence is?

Tags: calculus

I know for the formal definition you have to let $\varepsilon>0$ and there has to exist some $N$ such that $$\exists N \text{ s.t. } n \geq N,$$ and that $$|a_n - L| < \varepsilon$$

What exactly is a tail of a sequence and what does "there has to exist some $N$ such that $n\ge N$" mean? After reading my textbook and many other online resources I have no answer.

Comment: The tail of a sequence is all $a_n$ past a certain point. Basically, we don't care what happens in "the begginning" of a sequence (however, long that may be) because convergence only depends on what happens at the "end". As for the the existance of some $N$ for which $n\geq N$, basically, you can think of this as where the tail of the sequence for that particular epsilon begins.

Comment: An edit was submitted for my approval and bore a summary that began by saying this: "Corrected spelling and latex." Let us note that "latex" is a misnomer here. This is MathJax, not LaTeX. If you master MathJax and think you've mastered LaTeX, then you'll experience an unpleasant shock if you encounter actually LaTeX and find that you don't know it. I "improve[d]" (as the menu says) the edit, so it may look as if that edit summary was mine, so I feel some responsibility for pointing this out. I should have changed the edit summary before submitting it.

Comment: "there has to exist some N such that n≥N" is incorrectly phrased and is useless in this circumstance (what is $n$? so what if $N \le n$? This is all useless.)  The correct phrasing is "there exists some N such that ***IF** n $\ge$ N ***THEN*** something happens".  So for instance "there exists some N such such that if $n\ge N$ then anyone who is $n$ years old is dead which is true for $N$ being say... 157 but it isn't true for $N = 93$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition does not say there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ and $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon.$

It says there exists $N$ such that for every $n\ge N,$ we have $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon.$

Say you want to make the terms of the sequence differ from $L$ by less than $0.000001.$

That means you're setting $\varepsilon= 0.000001.$

Maybe the first billion terms of the sequence are not that close to $L,$ or not all of them, but after the billionth term, every term of the sequence does come at least that close to $L.$

That means $N=(\text{1 billion} + 1)$ is big enough.

Every term after the billionth term means every term $a_n$ for which $n\ge (\text{1 billion} + 1),$ i.e. $n\ge N.$

The sequence of terms after the billionth term is a "tail" of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The two displayed lines in the Q should be combined into a single phrase that says:

For any $e>0$ there exists $N\in \Bbb R$  such  that  $\forall n\geq N\;(|a_n-L|<e).$

This the  definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L,$ and the def'n of the phrase "$a_n$ converges to $L$ as $n\to \infty$."

Equivalently, $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ iff for any $e>0,$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: |a_n-L|\geq e\}$ is finite.

It is not necessary that $N\in \Bbb N.$

When the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges, the smallest possible $N\in \Bbb N$ usually depends on $e.$ Some students get bogged down in details trying to find the smallest possible $N\in \Bbb N$ (for a given $e$ ) when trying to prove that  a  sequence converges to a value $L$, not noticing that all you need  to prove is that $some $ $ N$ exists that fulfills the conditions.. That is if $n\geq N\implies |a_n-L|<e,$ then for any $N'>N$ we also have $n\geq N'\implies |a_n-L|<e.$

For example to show that $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $1$ when $a_n=1-\frac {n}{2n^2-1}$ for each $n\in \Bbb N,$  observe that $n\in \Bbb N\implies 2n^2-1=n^2 +(n^2-1)\geq n^2+(n-1)\geq n^2>0.$

So $0<\frac {n}{2n^2-1}\leq\frac {n}{n^2}=\frac {1}{n}.$ So  if $e>0$ and $N=1+\frac {1}{e}$ then $n\geq N\implies \frac {1}{n}<e\implies |a_n-1|<e. $

Equivalently, in this example, if $e>0$ then the set $\{n\in \Bbb N:|a_n-1|\geq e\}$ is finite because it is a subset of the finite set $\{n\in \Bbb N: n<1+\frac {1}{e}\}.$

A sequence can be defined as a function whose domain is $\Bbb N.$ So if we refer to a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ what we are saying is that $A_n=f(n)$ for some function $f.$ But in many circumstances this can be notationally awkward. I often abbreviate as  $(A_n)_n.$ Some writers and textbooks abbreviate as $(A_n)$ or $\{A_n\}.$ The latter  should not be confused with the usual set-theoretic notation for a set.